# Extending Clojure's Associative Abstraction to Java Library Types

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have an application (several actually) which decode JSON data in a Map using Jackson. Data appears to either be in a Map or ArrayList (in the case of JSON arrays.) The data that comes in on these streams is unstructured, so this won't be changing.

I own some Clojure code which accesses nested properties in these objects. Ideally I'd like to extend the Associative abstraction to these Java types so that `get-in` works on them. Something like the following:

```
(extend-protocol clojure.lang.Associative
  java.util.Map
    (containsKey [this k] (.containsKey this k))
    (entryAt [this k] (when (.containsKey this k)
                  (clojure.lang.MapEntry/create k (.get this k))))
java.util.ArrayList
  (containsKey [this k] (< (.size this) k))
  (entryAt [this k] (when (.containsKey this k)
                  (clojure.lang.MapEntry/create k (.get this k)))))
```

There are two problems with this; The first being that Associative is not a protocol (if it were this appears it would work). The second being that the types are already defined so I cannot add Associative with deftype.

I'm pretty new to the JVM interop part of Clojure. Is there a method I'm not seeing? Or is there a protocol which wraps Associative and will work with `get-in` that I've missed?

Thanks SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that half of the extension you want to do is already done, and the other half cannot be done. The [`get-in`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5909-L5926) function calls [`get`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1445-L1453), which calls [`clojure.lang.RT/get`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L733-L787), which calls [`clojure.lang.RT/getFrom`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L733-L787), which calls [`java.util.Map/get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) if the first argument is a `Map`. So if you have any Java `Map`, then `get-in` works (I'm borrowing this example directly from the [`doto`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doto) docstring):

```
(let [m (doto (new java.util.HashMap) (.put "a" 1) (.put "b" 2))]
  [(get-in m ["b"])
   (get-in m ["a"])])
;;=> [2 1]
```

However, Clojure does not have a `get` implementation for [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)s that support [`RandomAccess`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html). You *could* write your own `get` that does:

```
(ns sandbox.core
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [get])
  (:import (clojure.lang RT)
           (java.util ArrayList List RandomAccess)))

(defn get
  ([m k]
   (get m k nil))
  ([m k not-found]
   (if (and (every? #(instance? % m) [List RandomAccess]) (integer? k))
     (let [^List m m
           k (int k)]
       (if (and (<= 0 k) (< k (.size m)))
         (.get m k)
         not-found))
     (RT/get map key not-found))))
```

Example:

```
(get (ArrayList. [:foo :bar :baz]) 2)
;;=> :bar
```

Then you could copy the implementation of [`get-in`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5909-L5926) so it would use your custom `get` function.

I'm pretty sure this isn't what you want, though, because then every bit of code you write would have to use *your* `get-in` rather than Clojure's `get-in`, and any other code that already uses Clojure's `get` would still not work with `ArrayList`s. I don't think there's really a good solution to your problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Sam, hearing that there isn't really a good solution to this problem is useful. I'm very fortunate in that it actually all boils down to a handful of call sites for get-in, and have taken a similar approach currently. I'll probably slim it down further and make use of RT/get on your suggestion.

Thanks!